# My Minecraft server is running, however I can't connect to it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Help! I am running my Minecraft Server in CMD however I can't connect to it!

I am using a Sky router which is successfully port forwarded and on port 25565 - 25565. My server is running with my IP taken from the ipconfig command in CMD. 
I have my external IP (hehehe im not telling you what it is). HOWEVER [Can You See Me](http://canyouseeme.org) says it cannot see the port.

Please help.

Comment: If Can You See Me can't see it, then your port forwarding is not correct.  Double-check it.

Comment: Can you connect from your local network? Run "ipconfig" ond your server's console and connect to that address.

Answer (score 2):

If you are connecting to the server from the same machine the server is running on, you can connect to it just by using localhost as the ip. (of course everyone else will have to use the regular ip, but at least you will be able to connect to it)